# calculate $U(f,P)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Considering the function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ by

$$ { f }(x)=\begin{cases} 0\quad ,\quad x \in [0,1)  \\ 1\quad ,\quad x=1\end{cases} $$

and let $P=\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$. I am trying to calculate $U(f,P)$.

Here is my logic so far,
Let $\epsilon>0.$ Let $P_{\epsilon}$ be a partition of the interval $[0,1]$ where $P_{\epsilon}=\{[0,1-2\epsilon], [1-2\epsilon,1-\epsilon],[1-\epsilon,1]\}$ for some fixed $0<\epsilon<1$

Then looking at the definition of $U(f,P)$,

$$U(f,P) = \sum_{[x_i,x_{i+1}] \in P} (x_{i+1} - x_i) \sup_{[x_{i+1},x_i]} f(x)$$

So, $f$ is zero on $[0,1)$, hence also on $[0,1-2\epsilon)$

So how can I use my partition I selected to calculate this $U(f,P)$?

Comment: The sup of $f$ on the first two intervals of your partition are zero, and thus your sum for $U(f,P)$ only has one term - which is $(1 - (1-\epsilon) )\cdot 1 = \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from the question that you actually get to CHOOSE the partition; and, in this problem, it isn't necessary.  So let's stick with the generic $\{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}$, where $0=x_0$ and $1=x_n$.

Then
$$
\sup_{x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & i < n-1\\1 & i=n-1\end{cases}.
$$
Therefore
$$
U(f,P)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)\sup_{x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(x)=(x_n-x_{n-1}).
$$

Comment: so then what does this equal?

Comment: or do I only need to show what $U(f,P)$ is without calculating it?

Comment: I don't follow -- we DID just calculate it.  It is $x_n-x_{n-1}$.

Comment: yes sorry that's what I meant. The hint I was given for this problem was that the answer will depend on the partition $P$, in particular on the number $x_{n-1}$. I forgot to add this comment in. So then does your answer still apply? and thanks for the submission btw

Comment: Remember that $x_n=1$.  So yes, the answer is $1-x_{n-1}$, which matches up with the hint you were given.

Answer (score 1):

You can also say $f$ is zero on $[0,1-\epsilon)$, so the sup of $f$ on your first *two* of your three intervals is $0$ for each. On the third interval $[1-\epsilon,1]$ the sup becomes $1$ since $f=1$ at $x=1$ (and $0$ for the rest of the third interval).

This makes the sum become $\epsilon\cdot 1=\epsilon.$

Comment: so then how do I calculate $U(f,P)?$

Comment: The above gives $U(f,P)=\epsilon$ because only the third term is nonzero, and for it, the sup is 1 and $x_2-x_1=1-(1-\epsilon)=\epsilon.$